# Docusign for Salesforce crashing, Final variable has already been initialized (v 6.8.2)

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

Updated the Docusign for Salesforce managed package in Salesforce from version 6.2.1 (showing 6.8) up to the current 6.8.2. After doing so I'm now receiving the following when trying to access Docusign.

> Final variable has already been initialized  An unexpected error has
>   occurred. Your solution provider has been notified. (dsfs)

As an admin of the org I also get the APEX error email with the following pertinent details:

```
Visualforce Page: /apex/dsfs__DocuSign_Admin


caused by: System.FinalException: Final variable has already been initialized

Class.dsfs.PlatformPermissionSetService.<init>: line 32, column 1
Class.dsfs.ServiceLocator.getPermissionSetService: line 72, column 1
Class.dsfs.DocuSignConfiguration.loadConfig: line 366, column 1
Class.dsfs.DocuSignConfiguration.initConfiguration: line 338, column 1
Class.dsfs.DocuSignConfiguration.getInstance: line 214, column 1
Class.dsfs.ConfigurationService.<init>: line 32, column 1
Class.dsfs.ConfigurationService.<init>: line 20, column 1
Class.dsfs.ServiceLocator.getConfigurationService: line 60, column 1
Class.dsfs.ServiceLocator.getConfigurationService: line 50, column 1
Class.dsfs.AdminManager.findAdminDetails: line 12, column 1
Class.dsfs.AdminController.<init>: line 41, column 1
```

As a salesforce developer I see this as an error in the managed package code wherein they are trying to assign a value to an already initialized final type variable, likely related to a caching of Permission Set information.

I have already uninstalled the app in one of our sandboxes and reinstalled, this did not fix the error.

I installed this in a developer org that has not had the app installed before and it pulls up the VF page without issue.

Assuming this is related to my org but can't find anything in my control to manipulate. Unable to inspect the protected custom settings related to the app.

Was directed here after first level support told me they couldn't help me.

Comment: It sucks to redirect you again but try cross-posting to salesforce.stackexchange.com. It's likely more Docusign clients will see this question there. Debug log probably won't help much here... Docusign doesn't have any bugtracker? It sure sounds like something their devs should investigate, especially if debug log would show it's 100% their code running, no influence of your custom triggers etc... Having said that. Any chance you failed to read some release notes or upgrade manual (if any?)

Comment: Thanks, I posted here hoping DS support would find me. Have cross posted into the Salesforce side for more community help.

Comment: Known issue for Docusign, DFS-4536
After Install -DocuSign for Salesforce Error when accessing Package

Comment: Add it as your own answer & mark it accepted? I'd happily upvote it. Thanks for coming back to us with investigation results!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Known issue for Docusign, DFS-4536 After Install -DocuSign for Salesforce Error when accessing Package

Will update again once patched.